# Show that $Q_8$ admits the following relation using free groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, free-groups

Consider the group generated by $<a,b : a^4 = b^4 = e,a^2b^{-2} = e, bab^{-1}a = e>$.I would like to prove that $Q_8$ is that group. Set $X = \{a,b\}$ and consider the F(X) of X. We know that there exists a homomorphism $\phi : F(X) \rightarrow Q_8$ defined by $\phi(a) = i$ and $\phi(b) = j$.

I showed that $R = <a^4,b^4,a^2b^{-2},bab^{-1}a>$ is subgroup of the kernel. I would like now to prove that $F(X) / R$ is isomorphic to $Q_8$, but I have no idea how to do that. This example was from hungerford but he left out the details of things, so I decided to complete it myself. The book mentioned that all elements F/R can be written in the form $a^ib^jN$ for $ 0 \leq i \leq 3$ and $j = 0,1$, but why is that ?

Comment: The last relation can be rewritten as $ba=a^{-1}b=a^3b$. This allows you to "move $b$s to the right of $a$s" modulo $R$. For example
$$abba=aba^3b=a(ba)a^2b=a(a^3b)a^2b=a^7bab=a^{10}b^2=a^2b^2.$$ You can do this to any coset of $R$ and end up with the result that $xR=a^ib^jR$ for any $x\in F(X)$.

Comment: Oh, and an important thing: $R$ should be the **normal** subgroup generated by the relations. A kernel is always a normal subgroup. So for example to any $x\in F(X)$ we have $xa^4x^{-1}\in R$. This is why the generators of $R$ are viewed as relations - you can always replace one side of a relation equation with the other in the middle of a long element of $F(X)$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I would accept your answer if you post it ? Maybe it would be helpful for other people as well.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen just a quick question any $x \in F(X)$ will be just concatenation of a,b so how can I show this rigorously ?

Comment: I don't understand still how to solve this could you explain more @JyrkiLahtonen.

Answer (score 1):

It is the intention of the author that you show that both groups $Q_8$ and $F/X$ have the same structure. Let $C_i$ be the cyclic group of order $4$ generated by  $i$. This group is a normal subgroup of $Q_8$ because $i$ acts trivially on it, and the action of $j$ is given by $j^{-1}ij = j^{-1}ji^{-1} = i^{-1}$.The quotient group of $Q_8/C_i$ is of order 2 and let us denote it by $C_\textbf{j}$, where $\textbf{j}$ is the left coset of $j$.  Then $Q_8 = C_i \rtimes C_\textbf{j}$ the semidirect product of two cyclic groups and so every element can be written as $i^u\textbf{j}^v$ with $u \in \{0,\ldots,3\}$ and $v \in \{0,1\}$. The same can be said about $F/X$. Let $F_a$ be the group generated by $a$. It is a cyclic group of order $4$ (as can be seen by the first relation) that is mapped isomorphically by $\phi$ to $C_i$. The fourth relation, with a little rewriting, shows that $b^{-1}ab = a^{-1}$. If we denote the quotient $(X/F)/F_a$ by $F_\textbf{b}$ where $\textbf{b}$ denotes the coset of $b$ then $\phi$ maps $F_\textbf{b}$ to $C_\textbf{j}$ and so also the semidirect product $F_a \rtimes F_\textbf{b}$ $C_i to \rtimes C_\textbf{j}$; mapping the eight elements $a^u\textbf{b}^v$ to the eight elements $i^u\textbf{j}^v$.